# Guild Wars 2 necromancer mask

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is it possible to hide or not even use mask in character creator for necromancer class in Guild Wars 2? If yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to skip that step of the character creation as far as I know, but when you finish creating your character and get into the game proper, your "mask" is simply a regular head slot item that you can hide (or even remove) at will.

The same is also true for the Mesmer's masks.

Comment: I believe it is possible for all headgear, as well as shoulders.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Indeed it is! It's also worth mentioning that, because the masks are treated as normal head slot items, they can be used for transmutation as well. :)

Comment: Yes, they can. The thief's hood is only available as starter gear, but I much prefer that look to the masks you find during the game, so in the last BWE I transferred the appearance of the hood along as I got new gear.